# Angularjs custom component vs ngSwitch directive compilation order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-switch

There is a following code snippet:

```
<my-header></my-header>
<div ng-switch="$ctrl.page">
        <div ng-switch-when="1"><component1></component1></div>
        <div ng-switch-when="2"><component2></component2></div>
        <div ng-switch-when="3"><component3></component3></div>
</div>
```

I want that component **myHeader** would be constructed before **ngSwitch** directive takes an action. Now **component1** is constructed before **myHeader**.

Routing represents following code:

```
$stateProvider
  .state({
    name: 'myApp',
    url: '/',
    component: 'loader',
  })
  .state({
    name: 'myApp.pages',
    url: 'pages/{id:int}',
    component: 'loader'
  });
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/pages/1');
```

Comment: what `my-header` has?

Comment: my-header is very simple component implementing ng.IComponentOptions with HTML template and controller. Nothing special. Just maybe one thing it injects custom singleton service. Does it make any sence?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in plunker and add in question..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by exposing your controller in the link function inside the **myHeader** directive.

With that, you can easily add variables to the controller and control the visibility of the ng-switch div with **ng-if**. Check the code snippet down here.

Ah, don't forget to add [**ng-cloak**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) to the div containing the **ng-switch** directive.

```js
angular
        .module('app', [])
        .controller('TestController', function($scope) {
            this.page = 1;
        })
        .directive('myHeader', function () {
            return {
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    // With element.controller() we can reach the controller that is wrapping our directive. Then, we can simply set the headerIsLoaded variable to true.
                    element.controller().headerIsLoaded = true;
                },
                scope: true,
                templateUrl: 'my-header.html'
            }
        });
```

```html
<div ng-controller="TestController as ctrl">

    <my-header></my-header>

    <!-- Add a visual feedback so user knows the components are being loaded -->
    <div ng-if="!ctrl.headerIsLoaded">
        Loading...
    </div>

    <!-- If ctrl.headerIsLoaded is set to true, the ng-switch will appear -->
    <div ng-if="ctrl.headerIsLoaded"
         ng-cloak>
        <div ng-switch="ctrl.page">
            <div ng-switch-when="1">
                Page 1
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="2">
                Page 2
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="3">
                Page 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. At the end I came to the solution using rootScope events. Probably not the most elegant way, but result was achieved.